# Silverlight combobox does not update text when combobox content is changed on dropdown closed event

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-4.0

I have a combobox.  I change the text of the selected item (that was previously selected) to a word instead of blank text.  When the combobox closed it is still set to blank text instead of the text I changed it to.

How can i get the comobobox to refresh?

Comment: Please show us how do you feed that combobox and how you change the text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you generating your combobox items through an itemsource that is an Observable Collection?

This should then update your combobox when items are added/changed/deleted which is not available in a List structure.